# Facebook: Find old posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm looking to find old facebook posts using FQL. I tried this:

```
SELECT actor_id, message, created_time FROM stream
 WHERE source_id = me() and (created_time>date1 and created_time<date2)
```

but even if the interval between `date1` and `date2` is only one day, it only returns a fraction of the posts. So, I tried chunking them, but even at 1 hour intervals it still doesn't quite get everything, and I quickly approach the 600 query limit for stream requests.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I also tried adding a LIMIT clause at the end and it didn't hep

Comment: The `stream` table seems to be very limited in what it returns by design. I'm trying to query the `stream` on one of my pages to display photos others have posted to the page's stream on an external website. I can't get some of the older photos anymore (from June) no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Graph API? Something like this should help you out with pages:
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?value=1&base_amount=1&limit=25&until=1332873234

To query your own posts the url is a bit different:
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/home?value=1&base_amount=1&limit=25&since=1344348794",

You can test Graph API queries here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=40796308305%2Ffeed

Comment: can you please explain what the value and base amount variables represent? I cant find them in the graph api. Is there somewhere I can find other argument definitions that I might nto have been aware of? All I know is from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/. Thanks again! This looks promising!

Comment: I haven't found any documentation for these either. How I discovered them was that I run a sample query and in the end of the response there were links "previous" and "next" with these urls. So I think the only way to find out their meaning is to play around with these values in sample queries.